# Deserialize json object xamarin android c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, xamarin.android

I have little issue with deserialize json object.
My json from http url:

[Screen of my downloaded JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6J11.png)

I don't know how to deserialize to make dynamically creating buttons. I figure out how to create buttons with text, but I don't know how to make them with options that they have. I try to get these options in Windows Form app for test, but app will crash. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your classes should be something like:

```
public class Type
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool closedQuestion { get; set; }
    public bool multiAnswer {get; set;}
    public bool usesImage {get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public List<string> options { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should be able to deserialize your json, using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
List<RootObject> myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Newtonsoft.NET](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4xPTtm6XOAhURM8AKHbHsDJYQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newtonsoft.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNHZ6PbDkWbr7Cimlf9pJcHOOBQMfg):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

You can also make a pairing class and use generics:

```
public JsonClass {
    // Do this for each property you want to map.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="name")]
    public int Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="type")]
    public MessageType Message { get; set; }
}

public class MessageType {
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // etc...
}
```

then do:

```
JsonClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(json);
MessageType messageType = obj.Message;
```

Comment: This is my classes.
[link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNNTHZ5XJe4Z0JhdV8tbFh5ME0/view?usp=sharing[link]

Comment: Awesome! So using the example classes I wrote, put the correct `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="XXX")]` attribute above each property. `XXX` is replaced by the JSON name of the value. So, for this JSON string: `{ name: "Nick", age: "21" }`, we would have this: `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="name")]` above `public string Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: Useful tip: Use http://json2csharp.com to get C# classes and properties from a valid JSON string. Just copy/paste and you will be given the code in order to create the classes for `JsonConvert` to `Deserialize` to

Comment: @GeoffJames In all my years I've never seen that tool! Future me thanks you for the time you've saved me.

Comment: @NickBull no problem :) Working with a lot of APIs and web services certainly has its uses! There's also similar one for XML, too - in case future you needs to deserialize XML to C# objects: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: And just to completely blow it all out of the water - Visual Studio (2010 and up) has the ability to do it natively! (I only just found this out). Click `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON (or XML) As Classes` (providing you're in a .cs file). **HOW DID I NOT KNOW THIS BEFORE NOW?!** See this link: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2015/10/05/Creating-C-classes-from-JSON-(or-XML)-in-Visual-Studio-2015.aspx

Comment: @GeoffJames You are my serialization hero <3