# Is there a way to connect web server to my xamarin android app?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new to mobile development so pardon me if my question is not the proper question to be asked.

In my company, there is a **Telephone Directory** website which is I'm not the developer of it,
Now they want me to create a mobile app base on that website.
I've recently created the android app using **Xamarin.Android** with sqlite database because they want it to be accessible offline,

Now, everytime there's an update to the numbers at the Telephone Directory website. they want it to be syncronized to the mobile app, meaning, if theres an update to the database of the website, the mobile app should go online and get the new data from the web server and store it to the sqlite database.

Is ther a way to achieve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Could your website provide the Json data(New records need to insert the sqlite database)? If could, you can use `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize object,https://stackoverflow.com/a/38744135/10627299, then insert new records to your sqlite database.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: you mean we will create an API for the website?

Comment: Yes. create an API.