# How can I receive the following data in ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, onesignal

I am using the onesignal library for notifications in my application made in Xamarin Forms, I already receive them well but I want that by pressing the notification it detects the additionalData that I send you, how can I capture that data in my app.

{
    "app_id": "",
    "include_player_ids": ["d0ce5b74-8869-4cf3-af8b-0d6414ecacbd"],
    "data": {
        "message": "La data que queramos enviar aqui mismo",
        "title": "Contacto Servicio 1157",
        "notificacion": "666",
        "appName": "",
        "pageToOpen": "chat",
        "parameters": "{IdProveedor:104, IdCliente:202, IdServicio: 1113, IdServicioChat: 6598}"
    },
    "headings": {
        "en": "Title"
    },
    "contents": {
        "en": "Skype skype skype"
    }
}

Comment: are you asking how to deserialize json?

Comment: Yes, knowing in which method I can obtain that data and how to separate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize json object xamarin android c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743280/deserialize-json-object-xamarin-android-c-sharp)